# JButton and text smaller at Runtime

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a custom control extending `JPanel` with a couple of `JButton`s inside.

When I see them from the NetBeans Designer, they look with a given size. But when I put them on a form and I put the form in runtime, the size looks smaller.

This is [how it looks in the NetBeans Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWE2X.jpg), and [how it looks in runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khBbU.jpg).

Same for text onside `TextArea` controls.

Why does it happen? The meaning of having a design interface is to design something in a given way. If it looks different at runtime, there is no meaning :-)

Comment: It's most likely the layout you are using. It's trying to adjust as the rest changes size. Try `.setResizable(false)`

Comment: `I would have added images if possible (apparently i don't have the rights to)` upload your images to external sites such as [photobucket](http://photobucket.com/) and bring url here, we can edit and then image will appear.

Comment: I've added links to the images.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be the Look and Feel that you're using or any UIManager properties you could be setting. Trying doing a search for UIManager and see if anything pops up.